# How to assert two interfaces contain the same keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the interfaces `Foo` and `Bar`, how can I **statically** assert both types have the same keys?

**Background:** I have an interface that needs to be used as both a database DTO and also as a 'model' type. For the database DTO, primitives will be regular JavaScript primitives. For the 'model' type, primitives will be nominal types (e.g. `AccountId` instead of `string`, etc.). Currently, I am achieving this by defining 2 interfaces: one for the DTO, and one for the model. However, I want some way to ensure these interfaces don't drift:

```js
interface Dto {
  orderId: string;
  invoiceNo: number;
}
interface Model {
  orderId: OrderId;
  invoiceNo: InvoiceNumber;
}
assertKeysEqual<Dto, Model>() // Compiles OK
```

```js
interface Dto {
  orderId: string;
  invoiceNo: number;
  x: any;
}
interface Model {
  orderId: OrderId;
  invoiceNo: InvoiceNumber;
}
assertKeysEqual<Dto, Model>() // Compile ERROR ('Model' does not contain 'x')
```

```js
interface Dto {
  orderId: string;
  invoiceNo: number;
}
interface Model {
  orderId: OrderId;
  invoiceNo: InvoiceNumber;
  x: any;
}
assertKeysEqual<Dto, Model>() // Compile ERROR ('Dto' does not contain 'x')
```

Nominal types are defined using the following method. **However, more generally:** the shape of the key types could be completely different between the types. For example, in one type you may have `order: OrderId`, which could be replaced with `order: OrderEntity` in its "expanded" counterpart type.

```js
export interface OrderId extends String {
  _OrderId: string;
}
export function OrderId(value: string): OrderId {
  return value as any;
}
```

Any idea how to implement something like `assertKeysEqual`?

Comment: how do you define OrderId and InvoiceNumber types ? Because if I understand well your question, just define type OrderId = string; type InvoiceNumber = number; and the create a single interface that could be used for both Dto and Model objects

Comment: `OrderId` and `InvoiceNumber` are nominal types: I have updated the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's also a type-only solution that gives a somewhat readable error message:

```
type AssertKeysEqual<
  T1 extends Record<keyof T2, any>,
  T2 extends Record<keyof T1, any>
> = never

type Assertion = AssertKeysEqual<{a:1}, {a:1, b: 'x'}>
// ERROR: Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: 1; }' but required in type 'Record<"a" | "b", any>'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznCAnYBpCI4FECOBXAQwBsAeAKCigBUBGKCAD2AgDsATOKAJQgGMB7JGxIBrDPwBm1AEwAaKARYgAfLIoz6TVh259BwsSEnUa8xSrLKoAXigsIAN2RkyoSLATJgAS34sbHogo6Ji4hKQA3gQAXDQAvvJRsfIARtFQAOQMGXFWAPR5UFhcXADyXOkACkj8kCggmSkZUN6cALatcN4sAOYt-m7QGREK6TQA3FBxzSl4wFBIEPjei2z9UIOZPAJCJABEBHtQAD5Qeyl7ZkrKGQB0LpulQsgAkmu2EXGu4NAvLA78by8CAAOTwbRSyACnxcEXU3WYSAkBGBUAAIsB+FA4ZRKPpXmx0nBgEhuj1xupKN0AUDQfx0ixwZCkBTKF8qSxEcjUQBZfhsCBEbGUqD4pBvdJPAXitis3HUwHAkH0qB-GlKpnIOXsjY-QJeXz+WzwIJoDDYfDEEgY-jyPkCoj5QoAYX4bTA3iIEE4pVQZC+OP6XJR0BtwtxoueMqJJLJco56rpDM1LJFDHS5m18M5yG50HtgvDuLFEqgUoJ8f6ieV6TVitBKazlE2JoNfgCreC5rCVptdv5gqdUFd7s90GKZS4UAAFBkC0Rmmx+N67Px5gJOQRuplsgBKf1kQMI3Mh9GYot4qOl4mk3qVhW0mt2RvqHXHpGn+cXyPS0vlmX3v89ZPnWj4vhG6YKEoTa6u4nY+O2xqeF2oSWqQfZQPOVhQAUw5uh6XpFCU5QzhkNqLsunAsGuUAbsAW7+FkGT7nEQA)

UPDATE: In TypeScript 4.2+, type-alias preservation ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#smarter-type-alias-preservation)) allows for slightly more pleasant error messages, if you introduce extra type `ShapeOf` for the record:

```
type ShapeOf<T> = Record<keyof T, any>
type AssertKeysEqual<X extends ShapeOf<Y>, Y extends ShapeOf<X>> = never

type Assertion = AssertKeysEqual<{a:1}, {a:1, b: 'x'}>
// ERROR: Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: 1; }' but required in 
// type 'ShapeOf<{ a: 1; b: "x"; }>'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0geQGYB4AqA%20KBeKAJQgGMB7AJwBN0BrCEM1KTAGigQDsRsAoUSFACCAZxEQKwANIMRAUQCOAVwQAbdAA0oEAB7AInKiNiIUGAJrZ257XoNGTSCGk3ZcBThABuE3v3DQouKSAJZknPjCYhLSsooq6gDeCABcAIwAvuzJ6ewARilQAOQ6RRl8APQVUHKEhMiEhQAKFGSQkiDFeUVQIcYAtn0iIZwA5r0RAtBFiRyFaQDcUBk9eUrAUBQQyiFbVBNQU8XwTi6zqVCLUAVQAEQ6t0vlRQB0fkfI1BIAkvsEiRl-IJvpwvGQQiQIAA5JT9PISSIAvyJXhQCb6CioBCQqAAEWAZCgKLRaMoVB%20VEKImAFBGowWqJJIzBEOhZEKnFh8IoDLRgLRIwxWJxAFkyOTVETGaSvhRfoVPuS5VReUzQeDIVD2VAQSzNVyJKr%20YcAlFgsAwhECEEYjIQPJlGp0PiyOwxRLcFUoABhMj9MAhVQQYzIKS8QHE9ESYXQF1SklQMkUqk0umqgXq1lajkGnnSqA6QpcEBGxmC6PY6DuiCSyMypXyqCKinpiZ6tmFXUa6G50too420LhSKD2L2%20JOl1u8U13CMr21eqNKAtNoxTolHp9KCDMR0g5HIrV1SrdabbZKXYQfYjE2CIonMzOgnYV7h3iR8uYyt4gnxklJsqKa0mMrbMt22ZQJycKGoyxpfjGUDHv%209bJk2sq-GBmaatqXZZr2%20aFhw3B9negTREOVpmracSOuoU5ITOqhzmiC51A0zStO0oDFKUvQDEM%2063oeLqnhsWw7HsB6mg%20pjOBgx6vm8GRAA)

Answer (score 4):

You can check that the keys of each interface are a subset of the other:

```
type AssertEqualKeys<T1 extends object, T2 extends object> =
  [
    keyof T1 extends keyof T2 ? 1 : 0,
    keyof T2 extends keyof T1 ? 1 : 0
  ] extends [1,1] ?  true : false;

const areEqual: AssertEqualKeys<Dto,Model> = true;
```

That type will resolve to false if the keys drift from one another, and you'll be notified of the error.

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgEwnAkgqBeKBnYcCWAdgOZQBkUA3lAPo0BGcAhoQgFxQBEA9osp1AC+AbgBQoSFBSEAbt3wBjCADkArgFt6yTFEIatcclVoNmrDp2lzFK-fyFjRRYMgBmTJVAAiwblVFQULxIqOw4eETEYoFE1krK3Bx6mshigk6ELnDungCy3EgANv6BwchoHPAhaNFQsfLxiVKyDbYpcGmi4uDQAILY2MjAAKIAjqpMhQDSECDYADwAKgCMUBAAHi6s2EH0AFYQCsAANFCLAExrmxDbuwdHAHyYAVAA2i+BANaz3K5nqxstggdt8QL8zpcAPxQVYcAAMxw+UFB4IuVyBIJ+fxWUGhsKgcJeAF10TdgW9lsdliToVA8KpoBx3IVBo4FNxCLgoEw4BAxhNChx+oM4CNxpMZnN5j5uMd8kUnlh6RBHKIAPRqqDDa6sby+DJZHLQGUABUKqh2gLJOxlJW59AUSTsHVE6Q1UASAHcoGDVAByQrFAAWTBk0BYazgcF4onZnOA3N5-Mm5yFAyGyemswWpvN2DlBQghUVdLgDMc7u1QKg8qLBrcHmgtcKZotpNuzbtTAdTvaRkodEYLDCnG7CgEIld6s1wyjvB2HLpQegvLDcEG3J2nqLhVjHK5PL54sKAGY0yKxQLJTnfAWiq3sCXlRXNb1A1BiNwCtziEwiAA6Pd40TI8BQAFnPDNj2vaVfAfO8iwfJ8yxVUQgA)

Comment: Holy crap, the type system got really advanced in ts

Comment: well taking into account the edits in the initial question, not sure that this solution will work. Some "types" could be a function, this is not clear...

Comment: @Jerome OP here: the type of the keys can indeed be functions, but `T1` and `T2` will always be objects. I think this solution works fine.

Comment: If I could accept 2 answers, I would. Thank you for your solution, @chrisbajorin