# How to check if a type has all keys from another type but no additional keys?

Tags: typescript

I want to check if one type has all keys from another type but no additional keys, e.i. it's a subset. Basically, I need some function like the one below which would give me the typescript error if the TTo is not a subset.

```
function typeCheck<TFrom, TTo>(arg: TFrom): TTo {
   return arg;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `has all keys but no additional keys`? It's not subset but the same.

Comment: If you really need such a "subset", you can use `Parital`.

Comment: Can you give an example of two types that would be valid here? Because @DeanXu is right, "all keys but no additional keys" is the _exact same type._

Comment: I assume the OP means really that an object only has keys that are in another object too (which includes the condition that it doesn't have any additional ones).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and came up with this solution:

```
function typeCheck<TTo, TFrom = TTo>(arg: TFrom): TTo {
  return arg as unknown as TTo;
}
type ToTest = { a: string }

const exactMatch = typeCheck<ToTest>({ a: "a" }) // valid
const moreKeysInArgs = typeCheck<ToTest>({ a: "a", b: "b" }) //error
const moreKeysinTo = typeCheck<ToTest & { b: string }>({ a: "b" }) //error
```

You can see a code example on [TS Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAngBwKYGEAWGIDWAPAColwA0iJAYgE5wC2iAvNeQHwAUAhnQOYAuavSYBKYWTiIA3gFgAUIkR0MUEHSR9+iHgGdE4AmDgB3LQakBuRQF9FqTNTgkMeqK1m7h7ujDA69gqKEAjuiBgAHjzQALI8UBA4no7YeISkLm5Q3DLeiABEPAWItmIhYR6McKoA0hgoegCSYACCAgZsqbj4xOSu7rn5RQVUAEbCBWMlZRVg4dV1DXr+5Cnoab2ZAx4AZF4TiL7+gUM8k9OlYkA)

### Edit:

So i played around a bit and i noticed  that if you define your object seperately typescript can't infer the type correctly

```
function typeCheck<A, B = A>(arg: B): A {
    return arg as unknown as A;
}
type ToTest = { message: { a: string, b: string, c: string } }


//exactMatch
typeCheck<ToTest>({ message: { a: "", b: "", c: "" } }) // valid
const moreKeysInArgs = typeCheck<ToTest>({ message: { a: "", b: "", c: "", e: "" } }) //error
const moreKeysinTo = typeCheck<ToTest & { message: { e: string } }>({ message: { a: "", b: "", c: "" } }) //error

const y = ({ message: { a: "", b: "", c: "", e: "" } })
// inferred type of typeCheck: typeCheck<ToTest,ToTest>
const noError = typeCheck<ToTest>(y) //no error
```

You have to do it like this:

```
function exactMatch<A extends C, B extends A, C = B>(){}

exactMatch<ToTest,typeof x>() //valid
exactMatch<ToTest,typeof y>() //invalid 
exactMatch<typeof y,ToTest>() //invalid
```

So now you may ask yourself why do I need a third generic.
Imagine a function that checks if objA extends objB like

```
function Extends<A,B extends A>(){}
// valid, because every Key and Type of A matches B
Extends<{a:string,b:string}, {a:string,b:string,c:string}>()
// invalid because c is missing in the generic B
Extends<{a:string,b:string,c:string}, {a:string,b:string}>()
```

So now you may want to apply the contstraint that A extends B, but that won't work because you will create an error

```
function Extends<A extends B,B extends A>(){}
type parameter 'A' has a circular constraint.
```

And now the fun part: Typescript doesn't seem to have any issues when you bind the generic B on C first and ask A to extend C afterwards.
I really don't know why that happens and why the first solution doesn't work like expected.

If I find an answer I will keep you updated.

### Solution

```
function exactMatch<A extends C, B extends A, C = B>(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67027737/322042) looks more readable and relies on pure types only:

```
type ShapeOf<T> = Record<keyof T, any>
type AssertKeysEqual<X extends ShapeOf<Y>, Y extends ShapeOf<X>> = never

type Assertion = AssertKeysEqual<{a:1}, {a:1, b: 'x'}>
// ERROR: Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: 1; }' but required in 
// type 'ShapeOf<{ a: 1; b: "x"; }>'.
```